# Dynamic class toggle with switch and label

Tags: jquery, class, switch-statement, toggle

I'm thinking of ways to dynamically toggle a class on/off on button click, and also add a label to that button explaining what the toggle button will change. Something that looks like this.

```
                _________
Power          | ON/OFF  |
                _________
Lights         | ON/OFF  |
```

I want to make adding these buttons on the code-end as easy as possible, so I want to simply use "data" attributes for the class and the label of that button. Something like this.

```
 /* Class Toggled Attr */         /* Switch label */
<div data-toggle-class="lights-on-off" data-toggle-label="Lights">

</div>
```

And so with jQuery it should be easy getting the label attr and class attr and adding it to the DOM accordingly along with the switch and label and toggle switch. To make this easier to understand heres a non-working way that could help better understand.

```
                       /*label*/  /*class*/
<div data-toggle-witch="Lights lights-on-off">

</div>
```

The method above gets each label and class using label separator selector, while still in one attribute value, although with this method I cant add more than one toggle switch because its not valid 2 of the same attributes on one element. Any ideas on how I should do this?

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted.

Comment: I haven't attempted anything. Just trying to come up with a way to do this.

Comment: Check my demo for solution and rate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type= "text" id="tbox" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn" value="add buttons" />

    <div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{background:#0f0!important;}
    button.btn{margin:10px}
.ui-input-text.ui-body-inherit.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow-inset {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}
input#btn {
margin: 6px;
}
div#container {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    if( $('#tbox').val()!=""){
var tboxValue=$('#tbox').val();
 var btn = $('<button type="button"  class="btn" data-value="'+tboxValue+'">'+tboxValue+' OFF</button>');
$(btn).appendTo('#container');
  $('#tbox').val('');
    }
})




$("#container").on('click','.btn',function(){
  var innerHtml=$(this).attr('data-value');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){ 
     $(this).html(innerHtml+" OFF");
     $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else{
    $(this).html(innerHtml+" ON");
    $(this).addClass('active');

    }

});
```

**TRY This Demo IT HAS DYNAMIC BUTTONS with on off feature**

http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/oer4L8s2/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution that works for toggling multiple buttons also**
**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" data-value="power">power OFF</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn" data-value="light">light OFF</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{background:#0f0!important}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var items= $('.btn');

$.each(items,function(i,v){ 
    $(v).on("click",function(){
    var innerHtml=$(this).attr('data-value');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){ 
         $(this).removeClass('active');
         $(this).html(innerHtml+" OFF");
    } else{
         $(this).toggleClass('active');
         $(this).html(innerHtml+" ON");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/td935pum/4/

Note added jquery and bootstrap

Comment: The buttons wont actually exist in the HTML file DOM, they will be generated later with jQuery based on an elements data label and class attributes, Thats why I only want to use attributes. Guess I forgot to mention that.

Comment: how are you generating buttons on click of something and how many buttons

Comment: When a div elsewhere is clicked, a function runs and looks for the attributes of the element clicked. It will look for the label and class for the switch(the data attributes) and It will append the switch along with the label on another div elsewhere. It could be many switches with different labels and classes.